# Need help translating into an arrow function

Tags: reactjs, react-functional-component

I have this so far but need it in an arrow function on an existing form that is using react-hook-form and gatsby-plugin-intl

The form should be in the format below where I am also using useState for submission.

The code is checking for the value of the option selected to display a conditional field / I think I will need to use the watch API for this field, but first need to include the  into the complete form.

```
   const ContactForm = ({ intl }) => {
   
   const [submitted, setSubmitted] = useState(false)
   
   [...]     }
```

As opposed to

```
https://codesandbox.io/s/cocky-oskar-o2m6c
   
   class SelectOptions extends React.Component {
     constructor(props) {
       super(props)
       this.state = {
         fruit: 'Apple',
       }
       this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
     }
     handleChange(e) {
       this.setState({ fruit: e.target.value })
     }
   
     render() {
       const isComplaint = this.state.fruit
       let complaint
       if (isComplaint === 'Strawberry') {
         complaint = <div>How Are You Doing?</div>
       } else {
         complaint = <div></div>
       }
       return (
         <div className='mt-10'>
           SELECT ONE
           <div className='mt-2'>
             <select value={this.state.fruit} onChange={this.handleChange}>
               <option value='apple'>Apple</option>
               <option value='Strawberry'>Strawberry</option>
               <option value='Cucumber'>Cucumber</option>
             </select>
           </div>
           {complaint}
         </div>
       )
     }
   }
   export default SelectOptions
```

Comment: What's the specific issue?

Comment: When you say you need to convert to arrow function, do you mean to say you are trying to convert a React class component to a React function component so you can use React hooks? Function components don't need to be arrow functions, they can be regular `function` functions as well.

Comment: Yes. Thank you for helping me to clarify this @DrewReese that is exactly what I was trying to say.

Comment: Thanks for checking in @DaveNewton. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it's the way to learn, you have fully detailed docs -
https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html

But anyway, if it helps - it should be something like -

```
const SelectOptions = (props) => {
    [state, setState] = useState({})

    const handleChange = (e) => {
        setState({...state, fruit: e.target.value})
    }

    return (
         ...
         <select value={state.fruit} onChange={handleChange}>
         ...
    )
}
```

Comment: Thanks @RanAB for taking the time to spell it out for me here. This certainly helped me and I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

In react functional component you need `useState` from react to make a state. It's different than class component based. You can follow my code here. I have test it and works. Hopefully work for you to.

```
import { useState } from "react";

const SelectOptions = () => {
  const [fruit, setFruit] = useState("apple");

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setFruit(e.target.value);
    console.log(e.target.value);
  };

  const Complaint = (props) => {
    return (
      <div>{props.fruit === "Strawberry" ? "How Are You Doing?" : ""}</div>
    );
  };

  return (
    <div className="mt-10">
      SELECT ONE
      <div className="mt-2">
        <select value={fruit} onChange={handleChange}>
          <option value="apple">Apple</option>
          <option value="Strawberry">Strawberry</option>
          <option value="Cucumber">Cucumber</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <Complaint fruit={fruit} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default SelectOptions;
```

In there i make `Complaint` as component separated. you can make it in different file if you want to, and than import that as usually.

Answer (score 0):

General steps to convert class component to function component.

1. Function components instanceless and therefore aren't "constructed". Convert `this.state` into one or more [`useState`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate) React hooks.
2. Move `componentDidMount`, `componentDidUpdate`, and `componentWillUnmount` lifecycle method logic into one or more [`useEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect) React hooks with appropriate dependency array.
3. The ***entire*** function body of a function component is considered to be the "render" function. The function's return is what the `render` method returns.

Function component version:

```
const options = [
  {
    label: "Apple",
    value: "apple"
  },
  {
    label: "Strawberry",
    value: "strawberry"
  },
  {
    label: "Cucumber",
    value: "cucumber"
  }
];

const SelectOptions = () => {
  const [state, setState] = React.useState({ fruit: "Apple" });

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    // Functional state update to shallow merge any previous state
    setState((state) => ({
      ...state,
      fruit: e.target.value
    }));
  };

  return (
    <div className="mt-10">
      SELECT ONE
      <div className="mt-2">
        <select value={state.fruit} onChange={handleChange}>
          {options.map(({ label, value }) => (
            <option key={value} value={value}>
              {label}
            </option>
          ))}
        </select>
      </div>
      {/* Conditionally render the div */}
      {state.fruit === "strawberry" && <div>How Are You Doing?</div>}
    </div>
  );
};
```

[image: Edit need-help-translating-into-an-arrow-function]

- [Functional State Update](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates)
- [Conditional Rendering](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html#inline-if-with-logical--operator)